# Add Checkmark To UIActionSheet Button Similar To Airplay Action Sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am trying to figure out how to add a checkmark to the right side of a button in a `UIActionSheet`.

I would like to mimic the checkmark in the AirPlay action sheet. From what I've been reading, customizing these buttons means accessing Apple's private API and puts you at risk of being rejected in the App Store.

Is there a safe way to add this checkmark?

Comment: @epatel suggestion will work for me. When creating my `UIAlertSheet` I append `\342\234\223` to my button title. Still wish there was a prettier way.

Answer (score 3):

How about this method?

Place a label with a 'tick' inside the button and toggle that. Below is some code to do just that. The toggling is done though a KVO but can be done in simpler ways...

The button is connected in IB through `self.theButton`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create a 'tick' label
    CGRect rect;
    rect.size = CGSizeMake(17, 21);
    rect.origin.x = self.theButton.frame.size.width-17-10;
    rect.origin.y = (self.theButton.frame.size.height-21)/2;
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithCString:"\342\234\223" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.hidden = YES;

    // Put label inside the button
    [self.theButton addSubview:label];

    // Connect a observer on 'highlighted' (eq pressed basically)
    // could use another method to track 'selected'
    [self.theButton addObserver:self
                     forKeyPath:@"highlighted"
                        options:0
                        context:(__bridge void*)label];
}

// Toggle the 'tick' label
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(UIButton*)button
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(UILabel *)label
{
    if (button.highlighted)
        label.hidden = !label.hidden;
}

// Don't forget to cleanup
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.theButton removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"highlighted"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString* strUrl=[MLControl shared].currentServerUrl;
    for( MLServerUrl *title in [MLControl shared].arrServerUrl)  {
        NSString* strShow=title.name;
        if ([strUrl isEqualToString: title.url]) {
            strShow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"√ %@",strShow];
        }else{
            strShow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",strShow];
        }

        [chooseImageSheet addButtonWithTitle:strShow];
    }

   // [[[chooseImageSheet valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_check_black_18dp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    chooseImageSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [chooseImageSheet showFromRect:btnRc inView:sender animated:YES];
```